# Работа с массивами строк C++

Tags: c++, c, массивы, строки

Есть массив `masiv_C0 = {{A, B}, {A, C}, {B, C}}`

Есть массив `masiv_X0 = {{A, B}}`

Надо создать третий массив из первых двух:

`masiv_Y1 = masiv_C0 - masiv_X0 = {{A, C}, {B, C}}`

**Обновление:** [Здесь правильное решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/574712/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-vector-c)

Comment: проблема не раскрыта

Comment: Вы бы не могли внятно изложить свою задачу? Как должен быть создан X0, что означает C0 без элементов X0 - убрать соответствующую подстроку? весь элемент? И еще - вам позарез нужно делать все это через динамическую память?

Comment: 1. X0 это элементы массива C0 которые содержатся в подмножестве других элементов C0; Пример: C0={(a,bc);(fg,jkl);(agh,bcd)} => X0={(a,bc)}

Comment: 2. Задача, убрать из C0 элементы X0

Comment: 3. то есть Y0 = {(a,bc);(fg,jkl);(agh,bcd)} - {(a,bc)} = {(fg,jkl);(agh,bcd)}

Comment: У вас размерность массива Y *уже* задана. И как из него выбросить элементы? Что вместо них должно быть?...

Comment: Могут ли значения в массиве С0 повторяться? Если да, то наличие такого значения в Х0 должно удалять все такие же элементы из С0 или только один? Могут ли значения в Х0 повторяться?

Comment: Нет, значения не повторяются и не C0 и не в X0, в моей задаче такое не возможно

Comment: C++\malgrange1\main.cpp|164|error: 'remove' is not a member of 'std'| для решения этой проблемы проверть флаги компиляции и наврное нет заголовчника подробнее по remove тут http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку значения в массивах не повторяются (см. комментарии), то рекомендую использовать для решения задачи подходящую структуру данных [(несортированное множество)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/), что делает решение тривиальным:

```
unordered_set<string> C0{"AB", "C", "X", "Z"};
unordered_set<string> X0{"GG", "C"};
unordered_set<string> Y0{C0}; // инициализируем Y0 С0

for(string s : X0){
  Y0.erase(s);
}   //удаляем из Y0 элементы Х0
```

Update: из комментариев ниже выяснилось, что на входе и выходе нужны `string**`, поэтому я предлагаю сделать функции, преобразующие `string**` в множество строк и обратно. Ниже код целиком:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

 string** set_to_2string_ptr(unordered_set<string> data, int x, int y){
    string** result = new string*[x];
    for(int i(0); i < x; ++i){
        result[i] = new string[y];
    }
    auto ite = data.begin();
    for(int i(0); i < x; ++i){
            for(int j(0); j < y; ++j){
                result[i][j] = (ite != data.end())
                    ? *ite++
                    : " ";
            }
    }
    return result;
}

unordered_set<string> str_2ptr_to_set(string** str, int x, int y){
    unordered_set<string> result;
    for(int i(0); i < x; ++i){
        for(int j(0); j < y; ++j){
            result.insert(str[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main(){

    string** masiv_C0 = new string*[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        masiv_C0[i] = new string [2];

     masiv_C0[0][0] = "AB";
    masiv_C0[0][1] = "C";
    masiv_C0[1][0] = "X";
    masiv_C0[1][1] = "Z";
    masiv_C0[2][0] = "XY";
    masiv_C0[2][1] = "ZQ";

  unordered_set<string> C0 = str_2ptr_to_set(masiv_C0, 3, 2);
  unordered_set<string> X0{"GG", "C"};
  unordered_set<string> Y0{C0};

  for(string s : X0){
    Y0.erase(s);
  }

  string** masiv_Y1 = set_to_2string_ptr(Y0, 3, 2);

  return 0;
}
```

П.С.
Не забывайте следить за выделенной памятью и освобождать ее.
П.П.С.
Дальше можно сократить этот код, объединив конвертирующие функции внутри одной, которая, собственно, и создает разницу множеств.

Comment: Да, мне нравится ваш вариант, но у меня все несколько сложнее, мой массив - это вершины графа, и вся моя программа построена на работе с двумерным массивом типа string. То есть удалить элементы X0 из Y0 это только одна из операций которую я должен сделать в процессе обработке вершин графа.... Можно конечно попробовать работать с структурами, но на это уйдет больше времени так как у меня нет идей внедрения их в мою программу...

Comment: к примеру в ходе вычислений получаем такой массив : C0 = {(a, adf), (b, bcf), (c, bc), (d, adf), (e, e), (f, abdf), (ab, f), (ad, adf), (af, adf), (bc, bc), (bd, f), (bf, bf), (cf, b), (df, adf)}.

Comment: X0 - это элементы массива C0 которые содержатся в подмножестве других элементов C0: X0 = {(a, adf), (c, bc), (d, adf)}

Comment: мне надо вычислить Y1 = C0 - X0 = {(b, bcf), (e, e), (f, abdf), (ab, f), (ad, adf), (af, adf), (bc, bc), (bd, f), (bf, bf), (cf, b), (df, adf)}