# Работа с массивами строк vector C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, строки, vector

Есть массив `masiv_C0 = {{A, B}, {A, C}, {B, C}}`

Есть массив `masiv_X0 = {{A, B}}`

Надо создать третий массив из первых двух:

`masiv_Y1 = masiv_C0 - masiv_X0 = {{A, C}, {B, C}}`

Проблема в том что в третьем массиве который я создаю удаляются и отдельные элементы A и B.

В итоге, вместо того чтобы получить `{{A, C}, {B, C}}` я получаю `{{C}, {C}}`... Помогите исправить код! Спасибо заранее :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

typedef std::vector<std::string> String1D;
typedef std::vector<String1D> String2D;

int main()
{
    String2D masiv_C0(3, String1D(2));
    masiv_C0[0][0]="A";
    masiv_C0[0][1]="B";
    masiv_C0[1][0]="A";
    masiv_C0[1][1]="C";
    masiv_C0[2][0]="B";
    masiv_C0[2][1]="C";

    String2D masiv_X0(1, String1D(2));
    masiv_X0[0][0]="A";
    masiv_X0[0][1]="B";

    String2D masiv_Y1 = masiv_C0;
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < masiv_X0.size(); ++i)
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < masiv_X0[i].size(); ++j)
        {
            auto& str = masiv_X0[i][j];
            for (size_t cur = 0; cur < masiv_Y1.size(); ++cur)
            {
                auto iter = std::remove(masiv_Y1[cur].begin(), masiv_Y1[cur].end(), str);
                masiv_Y1[cur].erase(iter, masiv_Y1[cur].end());
            }
        }
    }

    String2D::iterator iter = masiv_Y1.begin();
    while (iter != masiv_Y1.end())
    {
        std::copy((*iter).begin(), (*iter).end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(cout, " "));
        cout << "\n";
        ++iter;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если каждый элемент внешнего вектора содержит вектор из двух элементов, то разумнее заменить внутренний вектор из двух элементов на объект типа `std::pair<std::string, std::string>`. В этом случае код будет более понятным. Также вместо обычных циклов `for` проще использовать циклы на основе диапазонов.

Программа может выглядеть следующим образом. Я сохранил названия векторов такими же, какие вы используете.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> masiv_C0 = 
    {
        { "AB", "ADF" }, { "BC", "ADF" }, { "CD", "BC" }, { "DE", "ADF" }
    };

    for ( const std::pair<std::string, std::string> &p : masiv_C0 )
    {
        std::cout << "{ " << p.first << ", " << p.second << " } ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> masiv_X0 = 
    {
        { "AB", "ADF" }, { "CD", "BC" }, { "DE", "ADF" }
    };

    for ( const std::pair<std::string, std::string> &p : masiv_X0 )
    {
        std::cout << "{ " << p.first << ", " << p.second << " } ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> masiv_Y1 = masiv_C0;

    for ( const std::pair<std::string, std::string> &p : masiv_X0 )
    {
        masiv_Y1.erase( std::remove( masiv_Y1.begin(), masiv_Y1.end(), p ),
                        masiv_Y1.end() );
    }

    for ( const std::pair<std::string, std::string> &p : masiv_Y1 )
    {
        std::cout << "{ " << p.first << ", " << p.second << " } ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы

```
{ AB, ADF } { BC, ADF } { CD, BC } { DE, ADF } 
{ AB, ADF } { CD, BC } { DE, ADF } 
{ BC, ADF }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

typedef std::vector<std::string> String1D;
typedef std::vector<String1D> String2D;

int main() {
    /*
    // это "мишени"
    String2D masiv_C0(3, String1D(2));
    masiv_C0[0][0]="A";
    masiv_C0[0][1]="B";
    masiv_C0[1][0]="A";
    masiv_C0[1][1]="C";
    masiv_C0[2][0]="B";
    masiv_C0[2][1]="C";

    // а это "образцы"
    String2D masiv_X0(1, String1D(2));
    masiv_X0[0][0]="A";
    masiv_X0[0][1]="B";
    */

    // это "мишени"
    String2D masiv_C0(4, String1D(2));
    masiv_C0[0][0]="AB";
    masiv_C0[0][1]="ADF";
    masiv_C0[1][0]="BC";
    masiv_C0[1][1]="ADF";
    masiv_C0[2][0]="CD";
    masiv_C0[2][1]="BC";
    masiv_C0[3][0]="DE";
    masiv_C0[3][1]="ADF";

    // а это "образцы"
    String2D masiv_X0(3, String1D(2));
    masiv_X0[0][0]="AB";
    masiv_X0[0][1]="ADF";
    masiv_X0[1][0]="CD";
    masiv_X0[1][1]="BC";
    masiv_X0[2][0]="DE";
    masiv_X0[2][1]="ADF";

    String2D masiv_Y1 = masiv_C0;
    // цикл по образцам
    for (int i = 0; i < masiv_X0.size(); ++i) {
        // цикл по мишеням
        //// идём с конца, чтобы при удалени не нарушать порядок 
        //// в итоге получается -1, поэтому счётчик знаковый
        for (int j = masiv_C0.size() - 1; j >= 0; --j) {
            // нужно ли удалять мишень
            bool todel = true;
            // цикл по символам
            for (int sym = 0; sym < masiv_X0[i].size(); ++sym) {
                // если хоть один символ не совпал
                if (masiv_X0[i][sym] != masiv_C0[j][sym]) {
                    // удалять не надо
                    todel = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // если нужно удалить мишень
            if (todel) {
                masiv_Y1.erase(masiv_Y1.begin() + j);
            }
        }
    }

    String2D::iterator iter = masiv_Y1.begin();
    // вывод
    while (iter != masiv_Y1.end()) {
        std::copy((*iter).begin(), (*iter).end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(cout, " "));
        cout << "\n";
        ++iter;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
A C
B C
```

Comment: @Merk30 именно так и выводится, моё решение работает как надо. Я клоню к тому, что вы скопировали коряво. Входные данные обновил. Я тестировал здесь: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp11_online.php

Comment: Я извиняюсь, но посмотрите на следующие данные, их я получил при обработки графа и [ваш алгоритм не совсем правильно их обрабатывает](http://ideone.com/eC1tHa)

Comment: В новом массиве должны быть и (`{CF, B}; {E, E}`) вместо них там лишние (`{C, BС}; {D, ADF}`) я рад что ваш алгоритм подходит для других значений, но мой граф он обрабатывает неверно :(

Answer (score 1):

Идя следами [Vlad from Moscow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/183394/vlad-from-moscow), т.е. используя STL - мне кажется, проще использовать множества и `set_difference`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>

using Data = std::pair<std::string, std::string>;
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    set<Data> masiv_C0 =
    {
        { "AB", "ADF" }, { "BC", "ADF" }, { "CD", "BC" }, { "DE", "ADF" }
    };

    for ( auto p : masiv_C0 )
    {
        cout << "{ " << p.first << ", " << p.second << " } ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    set<Data>  masiv_X0 = 
    {
        { "AB", "ADF" }, { "CD", "BC" }, { "DE", "ADF" }
    };

    for ( auto p : masiv_X0 )
    {
        cout << "{ " << p.first << ", " << p.second << " } ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    set<Data> masiv_Y1;

    set_difference(masiv_C0.begin(),masiv_C0.end(),
                        masiv_X0.begin(),masiv_X0.end(),
                        inserter(masiv_Y1,masiv_Y1.end()));

    for (auto p : masiv_Y1 )
    {
        cout << "{ " << p.first << ", " << p.second << " } ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Можно и вектора, но тогда их надо сортировать перед поиском разности.

Comment: Это не эквивалентные решения.  std::set_difference не удаляет все совпадающие элементы в исходных векторах. Например, если исходные вектора будут иметь элементы { 1, 1, 2 } и { 1 }, то результирующий вектор будет равен { 1, 2 } вместо { 2 }.. .